How to map shared memory to fixed address on older linux (version < 4.17)
I'm using shared memory to share data between multiple processes that run my code (written in c).
The data I need to share is many interconnected structs that use pointers.
Since it will be tough to get rid of these pointers, I thought about mapping the shared memory into the same address on each process.
I've looked at the mmap's man page and found the MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE flag, which does exactly what I want. 
However, it is only supported on kernel version 4.17+, which is sadly higher than the one I'm developing on.
Is there any safe (MAP_FIXED can override existing mapping) way to map shared memory to a fixed address on these lower versions?

This question is similar to: how can I detect whether a specific page is mapped in memory?. Notably, the author seems to have the same issue as you where they need to check if it's alright to call mmap with MAP_FIXED. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also look into shm_open and shm_unlink, maybe these could solve your problem?

Are you running 64-bit x86 processes?  You should be able to find unused memory in the 0x60000000000 range - there are 1,099,511,627,776 bytes in that range.  I suspect your systems have less RAM and swap space than that.  Just read /proc/self/maps and see if there are any lines that start with a 6.  If not, that entire range is open.  AFAICT it takes special effort to use memory in that range.

This is a classic XY problem: the real solution is to store offsets and not pointers, then have a base pointer and use the offset to index from the base pointer. With just a few macros you can make this painless pretty easily. Other than that, if you really want to go about mapping the address you will have to issue another syscall to check if the memory is already mapped. One like mincore().
